# Regular to match Mrs/Mr/Prof/Mx but not Mrs./Mr./Prof./Mx

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to convert British titles to American titles *ignore case sensitivity*.
For example, MRs -> Mrs.

I tried to use boundary `\b` but it still matches `mrs.` and `mrs`.

```js
/\bmrs\b/gi
```

This one below work but it matches `mrs` , not `mrs`.

```js
/\bmrs\b[^\.]/gi
```

[image]

How to match the `mrs`, not `mrs.`?

```js
const americanToBritishTitles = {
  'mr.': 'mr',
  'mrs.': 'mrs',
  'ms.': 'ms',
  'mx.': 'mx',
  'dr.': 'dr',
  'prof.': 'prof'
}

function translateTitle(text) {
  let newString = text;
  
  Object.keys(americanToBritishTitles).forEach((key) => {
        const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${americanToBritishTitles[key]}\\b`, "gi");
        
        newString = newString.replace(regex, key);
  });

  return newString;
}

['Hi, Mrs Na', 'Mrs. Hoa', 'MRs Nana', 'mRs ', 'mrs', 'mr ', 'Mr'].forEach(text => {
  // This line logs wrong answer
  console.log(translateTitle(text));
});
```

The answer should be as below

[image]

Comment: do not escape `.` in character class use it like this `mrs[^.]` or use negative lookahead `mrs(?!\.)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use both boundary `\b` and negative lookahead `(?!\.)` to solve it.

```js
\b/[some-string]\b(?!\.)/gi
```

```js
const americanToBritishTitles = {
  'mr.': 'mr',
  'mrs.': 'mrs',
  'ms.': 'ms',
  'mx.': 'mx',
  'dr.': 'dr',
  'prof.': 'prof'
}

function translateTitle(text) {
  let newString = text;
  
  Object.keys(americanToBritishTitles).forEach((key) => {
        // Regex was updated with boundary and negative lookahead here
        const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${americanToBritishTitles[key]}\\b(?!\\.)`, "gi");
        
        newString = newString.replace(regex, key);
  });

  return newString;
}

['Hi, Mrs Na', 'Mrs. Hoa', 'MRs Nana', 'mRs ', 'mrs', 'mr ', 'mr.'].forEach(text => {
      console.log(translateTitle(text));
});
```

I found an issue that uses *negative lookahead* only as `mr(?!\.)` will match both `mr` and `mrs`.

[image]

This regex `/(?:ms|mx|mr|mrs|dr|prof)(?=\s|$)/gi` in @eamanola answer is **incorrect**. I want to replace `mr` with `mr.` but his answer does not return the correct output. His regex is a hard code and cannot work with dynamic input with hundred items. I think people should NOT upvote it.

```js
const americanToBritishTitles = {
  'mr.': 'mr',
  'mrs.': 'mrs',
  'ms.': 'ms',
  'mx.': 'mx',
  'dr.': 'dr',
  'prof.': 'prof',
  // ... hundred items here 
  // so should not use regex as `(?=mr|mrs|...)`
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the followed-by space, for example:

```
 /(?:ms|mx|mr|mrs|dr|prof)(?=\s|$)/gi
```

[Playground](https://regex101.com/r/AJ30Ri/1)

to replace, you can approach it from other side, for example:

```
const reg = /(^|\s)(ms|mx|mr|mrs|dr|prof)\.(\s|$)/ig
const output = [
  "We watched the footie prof. 1 ms. 2 match with Mrs Na mr. 4 for a While",
  "Mr. Na", 
  "Mrs. Hoa", 
  "Mr Rabbit", 
  "Mrs Nana", 
  "AmrS", 
  "mrs.com",
  "AmrS.", 
  "mrS",
  "www.mrs."
].map(s => s.replace(reg, "$1$2$3", "g")); //$1 & $3 in case a space is included
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I must replace the matched string as the code in the code snippet. Your regex won't work if the input is large.

Comment: add \b to beginning: /\b(?:ms|mx|mr|mrs|dr|prof)(?=\s|$)/gi

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. I found 2 errors with your regex. Please take a look at my answer.

Comment: Good to hear, you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to optionally match against the period by adding `\.?` at the end of the string. This will include the period in the match if one exists, or just carry on as normal if not.

```js
const americanToBritishTitles = {
  'mr.': 'mr',
  'mrs.': 'mrs',
  'ms.': 'ms',
  'mx.': 'mx',
  'dr.': 'dr',
  'prof.': 'prof'
}

function translateTitle(text) {
  let newString = text;
  
  Object.keys(americanToBritishTitles).forEach((key) => {
        
        const regex = new RegExp(`/\b${americanToBritishTitles[key]}\.?\b/`, "gi");
        
        newString = newString.replace(regex, key);
  });

  return newString;
}

['Hi, Mrs Na', 'Mrs. Hoa', 'MRs Nana', 'mRs ', 'mrs'].forEach(text => {
  // It should log `mrs. Hoa instead of mrs.. Hoa`
  console.log(translateTitle(text));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but your answer is incorrect. `Hi, Mrs Na` should be `Hi, Mrs. Na`

Comment: Then I recommend you update the comment that indicates `// It should log mrs. Hoa instead of mrs.. Hoa` with the full set of expected output

Comment: Oh, thanks. My mistake. I should clarify the question.